# Report Viewer Font getting stretched on WIndows Server Machine only

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

I did a small app to make shipping bills, where a user enters the information they want and can either Preview (a form with a ReportViewer control is opening up) or Print direclty. The reportviewer uses a Local report embedded into the application.

**Example Here :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/z90z8.jpg

I have tried the app on a WinXP, Vista and Windows 7 machine and there is no problem, the report is previewed correctly.

But when installing it on the server directly (2003 R2, 64 bit) the Font are stretched (even Printing from the control). When printing directly (I created my own code to do it, the report is rendered in EMF and then prints it) I have the same problem.

But when saving in PDF or Word from the ReportViewer control the do appear correctly.

This is an annoyance because we remote desktop to the server to use our main MRP program, so using the program inside the server will be best, so we don't have so switch back to the desktop machine just for a single operation.

By the way this is the normal Arial Font, so it is not a missing font issue. Also the server does have a couple of Crystal (version 9 I think) and SQL server 2003 reporting runtime installed on them. This is using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Is it a problem to save to PDF first and then print from there?

Comment: if it's just for the Print button and would be automated then no. But from the preview window, knowing the users it would be too complicated, instead of just minimizing the remote desktop and doing it from their computer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with a virtual machine hosted on a Win2008R2 box.  The solution I found was posted by user [Cassisi](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=921005):

> the key to fixing the server itself is to ensure the desktop resolution picked up by the SSRS service is 1024x768 (i.e. a 4:3 ratio) if the server is being remoting into via Desktop Services.

As a workaround I am going to try the solution described in [his article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/ssrscustomprinting.aspx) on high-fidelity printing.

Comment: That is the reason, I have tested a remote desktop by changing the resolution and the problem is gone. I have "bypassed" the problem by disabling printing in the report viewer control (which is now only like a preview) and did my own Printing procedure that uses PNG instead of EMF.

Comment: Worked for me, too.  One important thing. You need to set the DpiX / DpiY properties high enough, e.g. 200.  if you omit that, the default value, which is 96, will get you a blurred printed document.

Comment: @Exulted I'm having same problem, but have difficulty in implementing the solution. Do you have some example code? Or some tips to point me in the right direction, like which event(s) to implement

Comment: Hi, check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95750/High-fidelity-printing-through-the-SSRS-Report-Vie?msg=4239746).  It should give you a start.

Comment: @Exulted Ofcourse I've seen that article and reviewed it multiple times, but somehow I cannot figure it out. I would like to prevent the font being stretched on the screen and printer.

Comment: @RolandDeschain in my case, the font is not stretched on the screen, which is why the article's solution works.  And when you write the font is stretched on the screen, do you mean it is distorted?

Comment: @Exulted Here I have an example how text is stretched and how it's supposed to look. Both on screen and printer it's being stretched. http://i.imgur.com/LxQdi.jpg

Comment: @Roland: I used the samplecode from here: ttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091(v=vs.80).aspx

I changed the DeviceInfo to PNG and only used properties DpiX and DpiY with value of 300. In the PrintPage method, change the Metafile type to Image and load it with Image.FromStream. The rest should work fine as it is. It's also probably a good idea to use Path.GetTempFileName() in the CreateStream method.

Comment: @RolandDeschain I think it's to do with the screen settings on your own computer.  Which text size do you use (100%, 125%, 150%)?  What's your default font (Segoe UI or MS Sans Serif)?  Do you use Windows XP style DPI scaling?

Comment: @ChristianHubmann I've tried the solution you have provided, but when I use value 300 for DpiX and DpiY any images on the report will be very small. If I use 96 the images will display properly but fonts are not smooth. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

This is a known problem and it took a long time for the Reporting Services and Dynamics NAV developers to investigate and dissect the root cause to a Windows Remote Desktop Protocol issue.

There are 2 solutions available:

1. Upgrade the VB2010 host machine to Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012.
2. Install the Windows Remote Desktop hotfix from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2768741 for Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Using remote desktop connection at 4:3 ratio resolution fixed it for me.