# Reportviewer font stretched while print and print preview time also font broken

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, rdlc, reportviewer

I have problem in Rdlc report at the time of print and print preview time .While i am clicking show report button every font ending digit are stretched and broken in C# windows base application.But application developed machine print clearly.why it will happens.

**Client machine Report Snap Shot image**

[image: SEE the every Ending digit of the report]

**Developed machine report snap shot image**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem when using Remote Desktop. The "solution" which worked for me was to change the screen resolution of RDP to 1024 x 768 .

see: [Report Viewer Font getting stretched on WIndows Server Machine only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136484/report-viewer-font-getting-stretched-on-windows-server-machine-only)

Answer (score 0):

In the RDLC report layout, try to maximize the width of the fields.  It looks like it might be due to some scaling/resolution and is truncating it.  So, ex: between the up/down divider lines of each column, utilize the full space (maybe less 1-2 pixels) and see if it helps resolve.  Since totals are typically expected to be larger (final rows), I would suspect that is the issue.  Even on the totals, I can see the opening/closing balance is SLIGHTLY chopping off the 272.60 value.  If you can, widen the columns slightly AND the field widths of output.

Comment: I have change it resolution and auto scale mode font to dpi Nothing change in report ...

Comment: @NandhakumarS, try to set the padding on the RIGHT-side of the output fields to something like 3 pixels and see if that helps.